# "Virtual hosts" for SSH

Tags: ssh, linux

We have a remote Xen server running a lot of guest machines (on Linux), with only a couple of IPs available.

Each guest machine should be directly accessible by the SSH from the outer world.

Right now we assign a separate domain name to each guest machine, pointing to one of the few available IPs. We also assign a port number to that guest machine.

So, to access machine named `foo`, one should do as follows:

```
$ ssh foo.example.com -p 12345
```

...And to access machine named `bar`:

```
$ ssh bar.example.com -p 12346
```

Both `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` point to the same IP.

Is it possible to somehow get rid of custom ports in this configuration and configure SSH server, listening at that IP (or firewall or whatever *on server side*), so it would route the incoming connection to the correct guest machine, based on the domain address, so that following works as intended?

```
$ ssh foo.example.com hostname # prints foo
$ ssh bar.example.com hostname # prints bar
```

Note that I do know about `.ssh/config` and related client-side configuration solutions, we're using that now. This question is specifically about a zero client configuration solution.

Comment: Go for IPv6 and IP address limitation is no issue anymore ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
                         foo  
                        /
Client ----- Xen server
                        \
                         bar
```

It sounds like SSH Gateway is what you're looking for.

Firstly, create 2 new users `foo`, `bar` on the Xen server:

```
Xen # useradd foo
Xen # useradd bar
```

Generate key pairs and copy public key to the `foo-server` and `bar-server`:

```
Xen # su - foo
Xen $ ssh-keygen
Xen $ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub foo-user@foo-server
```

*(Do the same for `bar` user)*

Now, from the Xen server (SSH Gateway) you can login to the `foo-server` and `bar-server` without password prompt.

The next step is to let the `Client` authenticate to the `Xen server` with public key:

```
Client $ ssh-keygen
Client $ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub foo@Xen
```

and the final step is make `Xen server` open a second connection to the corresponding internal server. Access to Xen, switch to `foo`, open the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and change:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...== user@clienthost
```

to:

```
command="ssh -t -t foo-user@foo-server" ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...== user@clienthost
```

The sample result:

```
$ ssh foo-user@Xen
Last login: Thu Nov 10 13:02:25 2011 from Client
$ id
uid=500(foo-user) gid=500(foo-user) groups=500(foo-user) context=user_u:system_r:unconfined_t
$ exit
logout

Connection to foo-server closed.
Connection to Xen closed.
```

---

```
$ ssh bar-user@Xen
Last login: Thu Nov 10 11:28:52 2011 from Client
$ id
uid=500(bar-user) gid=500(bar-user) groups=500(bar-user) context=user_u:system_r:unconfined_t
$ exit
logout

Connection to bar-server closed.
Connection to Xen closed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, but I know of no SSH server or proxy that supports it. You can't use the syntax you suggest though. You'd have to encode the desired host in the user name. For example `ssh -u jsmith@foo foo.example.com`. The `foo.example.com` just gives the IP address. The master SSH server running on port 22 would have to 'route' based on what comes after the @ in the user name.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution you can use a bonjour, uPNP, DNS/srv based ssh client/wrapper and advertise the services via those protocols. See: http://eric.windisch.us/software/zerossh/

Comment: In situations where bonjour works (local networks) you usually don't have strong limitations on IP addresses, unless you have a picky network operations group. You have trouble with limited IP addresses on public net systems where IPv4 addresses are limited.

Comment: I updated the question to further clarify that the server is remote.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote any answer that suggests using either Bonjour or uPNP.

Comment: Me too. But I can not downvote my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

This [crossed my mind](http://www.ale.org/pipermail/ale/2009-September/113441.html) a couple years ago, but it seemed like the answer was no.